# sort Alphanumeric values regardless of letters

Tags: java, alphanumeric, columnsorting

input -->   "123","01","123A","728R" ,"1234"
Output should be  01,123,123A,728R,1234

i tried the below but not giving expected OP.

```
public int compare(SO o1, SO o2) {
                    if(o1.getnumber() != null && o2.getnumber()!=null) {
                        if (NumberUtils.isNumber(o1.getnumber()) &&
                                NumberUtils.isNumber(o2.v())) {
                            Long val1 = Long.valueOf(o1.getnumber());
                            Long val2 = Long.valueOf(o2.getnumber());
                            if ("asc".equals(searchSO.getSortOrder())) {
                                return (val1.compareTo(val2));
                            } else if ("desc".equals(searchSO.getSortOrder())) {
                                return (val2.compareTo(val1));
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            if ("asc".equals(searchSO.getSortOrder())) {
                                return (o1.getnumber().compareTo(o2.getnumber()));
                            } else if ("desc".equals(searchSO.getSortOrder())) {
                                return (o2.getnumber().compareTo(o1.getnumber()));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return 0;
                }
```

Comment: What does this getNumber() returns and what is returned by v()? And from where this searchSO comes? And what is actual output here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be remove all non-numeric values from the String and then compare it. In order to replace the non-numeric values from string you can use below regex:

```
str.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Collections.sort(input,
    Comparator.comparingLong(s -> Long.parseLong(s.replaceFirst("^\\D*(\\d+).*$", "$1")));
```

This replaces the string with only the first digit group. Then it parses a long from it. From that a Comparator is constructed with a `compare` method.

Comment: this gives an java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "123A"

Comment: @juwil `replace` should have been `replaceFirst` as `replaceFirst` and `replaceAll` are the regular-expression replaces. Corrected. Thanks